# Inner product of two vectors in complex vector space in index notation

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Suppose $\vec{u}, \vec{v} \in \left(V, \mathbb{C}^{n}\right)$: by construction 
$$
\begin{split}
\vec{u} &= \sum_{i=1}^{n}u_{i}\vec{e}_{i}\\
\vec{v} &= \sum_{i=1}^{n}v_{i}\vec{e}_{i}
\end{split}.
$$

The inner product of vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ gives

$$
\langle\ \vec{u}, \vec{v}\rangle
= \langle \sum_{i=1}^{n}u_{i}\vec{e}_{i}, \sum_{i=1}^{n}v_{i}\vec{e}_{i}\rangle.
$$

But $\langle\ \vec{u}, \vec{v}\rangle = \langle\ \vec{v}, \vec{u}\rangle^{*}$ with $*$ being the complex conjugate, and recalling that $\langle\ X,\alpha Y\rangle = \alpha^{*} \langle\ X,Y\rangle$ for $\alpha$ a complex scalar, this gives
$$
\left(\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}u_{i}^{*}v_{j}\langle\ \vec{e}_{j}, \vec{e}_{i}\rangle \right)^{*}
=\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}u_{i}v_{j}^{*}
\langle\ \vec{e}_{j}, \vec{e}_{i} \rangle.
$$

This is in contrast to the following

[image]

At which point is my argument flawed? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you done in the last expression?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh I have merely applied the skew symmetry property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must take care that there are two different conventions:

In some cases the hermitian inner product is defined as $\langle u,v \rangle=u^t\bar{v}$,

in other cases it is defined as  $\langle u,v \rangle=\bar{u}^t v=u^*v$ (mostly in quantum mechanics, Dirac's bra-ket notations)

Further details [Alternative definitions, notations and remarks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space)

It is the origin of the confusion, in your first statement you use the first convention, in the last one, the second one.